# Make something happen only when a form validates

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

How can I call a function only when a form validates?

My submit button opens a modal when pressed, but it does this even when the form does not validate. How can I tie the modal to the validation aspect so that the modal only shows when the form is valid?

HTML:

```
<head>
   <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery-validate.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/modalEffects.js"></script>
```

```
            <div class="md-modal md-effect-16" id="modal-16">
               <div class="md-content">
                   <h3>Thank you for signing up!</h3>
                   <div>
                       <p>We're excited to have you onboard as launch in late July.</p>
                       <ul>
                           <li><strong>Read:</strong> Check your email. Make sure you're subscribed to the email list.</li>
                           <li><strong>Surprise:</strong> Thanks for believing in us. As a gesture of thanks, you're getting the first batch of $50 giftcards to use on VERSEUX.</li>
                           <li><strong>Share:</strong> There are still some giftcards left. Share them with your friends, family, and fashionistas.</li>
                       </ul>
                       <button class="md-close">Close me!</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="md-overlay"></div><!-- the overlay element -->

   <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
   <script src="js/modalEffects.js"></script>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuPPy/1269/)

The JS and CSS code is pretty long, so It's on the fiddle

Comment: Your JSFiddle link doesn't work, please recheck your URL, thanks

Comment: He forgot to add js [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuPPy/1269/)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430839/how-do-i-only-show-a-modal-when-the-form-is-valid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"My submit button opens a modal when pressed, but it does this even when the form does not validate. How can I tie the modal to the validation aspect so that the modal only shows when the form is valid?"*

Within the  jQuery Validate plugin, the `submitHandler` callback function only fires on the click of the submit button when the form is valid.  So you'd trigger the opening of your modal from inside this.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

However, despite that you've included the jQuery Validate plugin files in your code, you are not using the `.validate()` method anyplace in your OP or your jsFiddle.